# Ignore / override Sinon error replace `TypeError: Attempted to replace foo which is already replaced`

Tags: javascript, sinon

I have mocked / replaced a method on an object. During the test I want to replace the replacement so that it returns / async yields something new. Is there anyway to pass "force" or something like that to replace. I know that it's already replaced, please Sinon, just go ahead and replace the current replacement with this one.

```
import sinon from "sinon";
import * as bar from "./bar";
import * as foo from "./foo";

describe("availabilityWorker", () => {
  describe("sync", () => {
    let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;

    beforeEach(async () => {
      sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
      sandbox.replace(bar, "bar", () => {});
      sandbox.replace(foo, "foo", async function* () {
        yield { error: undefined, data: { hello: "world" } };
      });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      sandbox.restore();
    });

    it("should do what I tell it", async () => {
      {
        // part 1 - (throws errors here )
        sandbox.replace(foo, "foo", async function* () {
          yield { error: undefined, data: { hello: "world2" } };
        });
        // ... assertions
      }

      {
        // part 2
        sandbox.replace(foo, "foo", async function* () {
          yield { error: undefined, data: { hello: "world3" } };
        });
        // ... assertions
      }
    });
  });
});
```

note I don't want to just do `sandbox.restore()` because that will restore everything, I just want to override `foo`